# Automating a large operation by making a function

Tags: functions, function-construction, iterators

I would like to automate the following operation. To be transparent I shall put my code into separate chunks and explain the process. Suppose I have the following:

```
ELPr = Map[DeleteDuplicates, 
   WordList[Language -> "English"] // Characters // ToLowerCase];
```

which basically makes English words into characters without duplication of letters in each words. I am going to make a polynomial also which measures the length of words by numbers that is,

```
ELPrPo = Total[x^Map[Length, ELPr]];
```

The rest of my code would be as follow:

```
out = Import["path/out.csv"];
l = Replace[out, 
   s_String :> 
    If[StringMatchQ[s, "[" ~~ ___ ~~ "]"], 
     ToExpression["{" <> StringTake[s, {2, -2}] <> "}"], {s}], {2}];
t1 = l[[All, 1, 1]];
t2 = Table[x^-2 Total[x^l[[i, 2]]], {i, Length[l]}];
LPairPo = AssociationThread[t1, t2];
Map[Expand, ELPrPo + x LPairPo - x^2 LPairPo];
Map[Expand, 
   Table[%[[i]] - 1/(26 + 1) x D[%[[i]], x], {i, Length[l]}]] // N;
LPairQo = AssociationThread[t1, %];
ξ = LPairQo/ELPrPo;
q = TakeLargest[ξ /. x -> 2/(26 + 1) // N, 1];
```

In my directory I have number of `out.csv` files named as `out`, `out1`, `out2` and so on for each I want to import them and find the `q` value. Once the `q` value is returned I do the following:

```
g1 = ELPr //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[
      Flatten[StringSplit[#, ":"] &@Keys[q]][[1]], 
      Flatten[StringSplit[#, ":"] &@Keys[q]][[2]], p___]} :> {Keys[q],
      p};
ELPrPo1 = Total[x^Map[Length, g1]];
Export["Desktop/LIMS/LIMS13/Language/ELPr1.csv",g1]
```

which essentially makes a new `ELPr` list now calling it `g1` and its corresponding polynomial `ELPrPo1` as explained in the beginning of this post. I now do the same calculations again:

```
out = Import["path/out1.csv"];
l = Replace[out, 
   s_String :> 
    If[StringMatchQ[s, "[" ~~ ___ ~~ "]"], 
     ToExpression["{" <> StringTake[s, {2, -2}] <> "}"], {s}], {2}];
t1 = l[[All, 1, 1]];
t2 = Table[x^-2 Total[x^l[[i, 2]]], {i, Length[l]}];
LPairPo = AssociationThread[t1, t2];
Map[Expand, ELPrPo1 + x LPairPo - x^2 LPairPo];
Map[Expand, 
   Table[%[[i]] - 1/(26 + 2) x D[%[[i]], x], {i, Length[l]}]] // N;
LPairQo = AssociationThread[t1, %];
ξ = LPairQo/ELPrPo;
q = TakeLargest[ξ /. x -> 2/(26 + 2) // N, 1]
```

But this one by `q` value is being calculated based on `out1.csv`, `ELPrPo1`, and the numerical value which was `2/(26+1)` is now `2/(26+2)`. I wonder how can I make this iterations automated namely to go through `out.csv` files, find new value for `q` with appropriate numerics (namely changing `2/(26+1)` to `2/(26+2)` and then `2/(26+3)` and so on on each iteration), make a new list `g1`,`g2`,`g3` and their corresponding polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes:

```
automateStuff[j_] := Block[{out, l, t1, t2, LPairPo, m1, m2, xi, q, ELPrPo1},
out = Import["path/out"<>ToString[j]<>".csv"];
l = Replace[out, 
   s_String :> 
    If[StringMatchQ[s, "[" ~~ ___ ~~ "]"], 
     ToExpression["{" <> StringTake[s, {2, -2}] <> "}"], {s}], {2}];
t1 = l[[All, 1, 1]];
t2 = Table[x^-2 Total[x^l[[i, 2]]], {i, Length[l]}];
LPairPo = AssociationThread[t1, t2];
m1 = Map[Expand, ELPrPo1 + x LPairPo - x^2 LPairPo];
m2 = Map[Expand, 
   Table[m1[[i]] - 1/(26 + 1 + j) x D[m1[[i]], x], {i, Length[l]}]] // N;
LPairQo = AssociationThread[t1, m2];
xi = LPairQo/ELPrPo;
q = TakeLargest[xi /. x -> 2/(26 + 1 + j) // N, 1];
g[j] = ELPr //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[
      Flatten[StringSplit[#, ":"] &@Keys[q]][[1]], 
      Flatten[StringSplit[#, ":"] &@Keys[q]][[2]], p___]} :> {Keys[q],
      p};
ELPrPo1 = Total[x^Map[Length, g1]];
Export["Desktop/LIMS/LIMS13/Language/ELPr"<>ToString[j]<>"1.csv",g[j]]
]
```

In general, indexed things like your `g1, g2` etc. are best represented by `g[1], g[2]` etc. in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks, I've imposed the changes yet this generates wrong results in many levels. I've tried to fix the indexing but does not work properly still.

Comment: Why would you not localize your variables if you're gonna put them in a `Block`...? What you did here is no different than taking all the code and putting it in parentheses.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Of course I should have localized the variables, but that does not address OP's problem. The important part is the use of `g[1]` instead of `g1` and how to use `j` programmatically in a few places.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer better to put completely good code on the site rather than mostly bad code. 80% of what's here is bad already, let's not increase the amount.